# Receiving [Error: Internal] in RN app when triggering a Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I have a Google Cloud Function which I am calling from my RN app but it is returning

> **[Error: Internal]**

I have set the permission to **Unauthenticated users** so anyone can call it - for testing purposes only. When I set to Authenticated users permission, it throws another error [Error: Unauthenticated] eventhough I am authenticated and I can get the currentUser id in my app.

Tried searching for this error but it didnt send me to any possible solutions so decided to post here and hopefully recieve responses that will help me fix it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

try {

    //Checking that the user calling the Cloud Function is authenticated
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('The user is not authenticated. Only authenticated Admin users can create new users.');
    }

    const newUser = {
        email: data.email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: data.password,
        disabled: false
    }
    const role = data.role;
    const userRecord = await admin
        .auth()
        .createUser(newUser);
    const userId = userRecord.uid;
    const claims = {};
    claims[role] = true;
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, claims);
    return { result: 'The new user has been successfully created.' };
} catch (error) {
    if (error.type === 'UnauthenticatedError') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', error.message);
    } else if (error.type === 'NotAnAdminError' || error.type === 'InvalidRoleError') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', error.message);
    } else {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);
    }
}
});
```

in my RN app I am calling it like this:

```
    var user = {
                role: role
               }

    const defaultApp = firebase.app();
    const functionsForRegion = defaultApp.functions('europe-west1');
    const createUser = await functionsForRegion.httpsCallable('createUser');
    createUser(user)
            .then((resp) => {
                //Display success
             });
                console.log(resp.data.result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error on register patient: ", error)
            });
```

I think the way I am calling it in my RN app is correct because I have tested it with a testFunction and I returned a simple string. So, I believe the problem is somewhere in the function itself.

**EDIT:** I just tested by simply calling the function and returning the context and it always returns Internal error:

```
exports.registerNewPatient = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall((data, context) => {
 return context; //this is returned as INTERNAL error. 
}
```

I just cant get to understand whats going on here, why does it return Internal error when I am authenticated as a user and it should return the authenticated user data, isn't that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try some `console.log(context) ; console.log(data)` statements in your registerNewPatient function and take a look at the logs. What do they say?

Some other things to consider might include that in your client code you use `europe-west1` while your function code has `europe-west3`. Try to have those line up and see if it works? From my experience, if a specified function isn't found to exist, the client receives an INTERNAL error.

Comment: I just changed to europe-west1 and still doesn't work. I tried logging context and its empty , data are being sent tho. So, there is something wrong with the context, do I have to pass it somewhere when triggering the function or it automatically sends the context of the current user?

Comment: Could you share all the relevant code somewhere like https://pastebin.com, and also share what the exact logs are? Is context null or an empty object?

Comment: context is an empty object. What else would you like to share? The code above reproduces the error.

Comment: It would be useful to see your updated code in one place, which generally helps with helping with debugging online. For instance the code above could be outdated with `europe-west3` or `europe-west1` and also `createUser` / `registerNewPatient` are different from each other, and I'd like to see where exactly your `console.log()`s are. Especially as this is a pretty strange bug, more clarity would help pinpoint the errorr